# Different speed on VLFs in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, transaction-log

As the topic says, can VLFs in the same logfile have different speeds?

Yesterday when I updated a table with 12M records, the update speed was about 5x when VLFa was active vs VLFb, is this normal and do anyone know why?

A little more background, the logfile had auto-growth 10%, this phenomenon occurred with two of the auto=growth VLFs.

I have changed the auto-growth settings to fixed. The log file was around 10GB I think and looked something like this, I think it was 16 at 400MB, then 640MB, 709MB, 780MB, 858MB, 944MB and maybe one more.

It was when the VLF at 858MB was active that the update was really slow, when the VLF at 944MB got active the update sped up. The log file didn't grow during the update.

I want to understand why the update was so much faster when the VLF at 944MB was active compared to the one at 858MB.

We run our DB in simple mode, The DB is around 400GB. The table I updated was 450MB and is now 790MB, so it was around 350MB of data ~11 million rows. The DB is part of a data warehouse, and a lot of data is loaded every night.

When I monitored the log file, I noticed that the update took much longer when one of the VLFs was active compared to when another one was.

Comment: Do you know that the time difference was due to a difference disk write throughput vs some other factor?

Answer (score 1):

> As the topic says, can VLFs in the same logfile have different speeds?

Without getting too pedantic or lost in the weeds, the answer is that all things being equal between the items, one is not faster than the other, no.